# pattern match using if condition in tcsh

Tags: linux, unix, pattern-matching, csh, tcsh

I am trying all sorts of combinations to do pattern matching using tcsh (cannot avoid tcsh). I runa command and then parse (using space) it. It works well. However, it doesnt do pattern match when I want to get a number from it.
It never goes inside if loop to give me "loop" output.

```
echo "Command: $command\n"
set tg_activity = `$command`
foreach abc (`echo $tg_activity`)
echo "The part is: $abc"
 if ( "$abc" =~ ^[0-9]* ) then
   echo "loop"
   set job_id = "$abc"
   break
 endif
echo "No If\n"
end
```

If i use $abc instead of "$abc" inside if condition, it gives me error"if: Missing file name.". "$abc" works well here as it does pattern matching with any (*) and gives "loop" output. The problem is in the condition statement (narrowed down). How can I pattern match here. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

foreach elem ($tg_activity:q)
     if **($elem:q =~ [0-9]*[0-9]?)** then
       set job_id = `echo $elem:q`
       break
    endif
end

Above worked for me